# filter image using if statements in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to filter several images from an `ImageCollection` according to the date and display them on the map. But when get the date property of an image, it prompts an error: `img.get is not a function`.

```
// s2Reduce is an ImageCollection
print('s2Reduce', s2Reduce)
// the specified date
var checkDate = '2020-01-03';

function checkImg(img){
  print(img)
  var formatDate= img.get('system:time_start');
  var flag = ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(checkDate, formatDate);
  img.evaluate(function (flag) {
      if (flag) {  
        Map.addLayer(img.clip(bb), visualization, checkDate);
      }
  })
  return img;
}

s2Reduce.evaluate(function(s2Reduce){
  s2Reduce.features.map(checkImg)
})
```

[image]

Comment: without a reproducible example it will be hard to tell but your error tells you what the problem is. Your variable s2Reduce.features probably are no images but features or need to be explicitly casted as an image.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.